# Meta analysis of standardised mean differences

Tags: mean, meta-analysis, standardization

I just had  a couple questions regarding meta analysing normal random variables that are from different but comparable questionnaire scores.

I have read that when you have a situation like this it is best to compute standardised mean differences. I was just wondering, if there would be any drawback from standardising individual trial arms and pooling results that way?

Also, the method for calculating the fixed effect estimate uses the pooled standard deviation however, as the SMD is a standardised random variable, shouldn't the standard deviation equal 1 and that be used instead?